# React native How to get value from Pressable/Text

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Hello i am new to reavt native and i don't understand how csn i get the value from Pressable/Text componente
I mean
I have a gender select on my app
Which has Pressable and inside this a
Text
When the user click it should updste the state to this value that selected
But i cant do it...

```
const SignUpPageButtons = ({ label }) => {
  const [toggleColor, setToggleColor] = useState(false);

  return (
    <>
    
      <Pressable
    
        style={[{ backgroundColor: toggleColor ? "green" : "white" }, styles.button]}
        onPress={() => {
       
          setToggleColor(!toggleColor);
        }}
      >
        <Text style={[{ color: toggleColor ? "white" : "green" }, styles.button_text]}>{label}</Text>
      </Pressable>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: your data save and update in "toggleColor" state so you should change {lable} to {toggleColor}

Comment: NoToggle color is state for when click on pressable it change the background color this is the purpose of toggle color and label is the string that use on the text (because i using map on this componente so label is the string that contain "men")

Answer (score 0):

i would make `const [toggleColor, setToggleColor] = useState(false);` on the parent, then pass it on SignUpPageButtons props like this `<SignUpPageButtons label={label} toggleColor={toggleColor} setToggleColor={setToggleColor} />`

then in SignupPageButtons use it like this...

```
const SignUpPageButtons = ({ label, toggleColor, setToggleColor }) => {
  return (
    <>
    
      <Pressable
    
        style={[{ backgroundColor: toggleColor ? "green" : "white" }, styles.button]}
        onPress={() => {
       
          setToggleColor(!toggleColor);
        }}
      >
        <Text style={[{ color: toggleColor ? "white" : "green" }, styles.button_text]}>{label}</Text>
      </Pressable>
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check this : https://snack.expo.dev/S8wZMuwRH

```js
import {React, useState} from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet,Pressable } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';


const SignUpPageButtons = ({ label, toggleColor,setToggleColor }) => { 

  return (
    <>
      <Pressable
    
        style={[{ backgroundColor: toggleColor ? "green" : "white" }, styles.button]}
        onPress={() => {
          setToggleColor(!toggleColor);
        }}
      >
        <Text style={[{ color: toggleColor ? "white" : "green" }, styles.button_text]}>{label}</Text>
      </Pressable>
    </>
  );
};


export default function App() {
const [toggleColor, setToggleColor] = useState(false);



  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
     <SignUpPageButtons label={toggleColor?"green":"white"} toggleColor={toggleColor} setToggleColor={setToggleColor} />

    </View>
  );
}



const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  paragraph: {
    margin: 24,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
});
```

Hope it helps,

Comment: hey
thanks for your time!
i didnt understand where is the change value start?
i mean
i need when i press the button i get the specific text?
because i need to create state that when i press the pressable i will get the inside text that inside Text components